# Is any complete example for merge or split table cells in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am working on a web project, one of the features include user can design a html table and  allow user split or merge cells feel free, (I am using jQuery for my project). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a small class to keep the attributes of the table in question and then as required rewrite the InnerHTML of it. While it sounds simple to adjust the colspan attribute of a td element this does not allow you to add columns or rows. it only allows you to extend the column or row you have.

Comment: I tried to do merge cells,But it is hard. Can you share your code for me?thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just found a jquery plugin to merge and split table cells.

Here is the link :
http://www.redips.net/javascript/table-td-merge-split/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need help with.  You need to set or remove the colspan attribute on a TD element.

Answer (score 0):

The TinyMCE table plugin does exactly what you need. In case you don't know, it's a full-featured wysiwyg html/text editor which outputs html code.

It's open source and you can take a look at it:

http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php

I am in need of the same functionality and was hoping to be able to scrap it from there, maybe implement a jQuery version, but unfortunately the code is too complex for me.

There are other similar wysiwyg editors but, to my knowledge, none of them offers the same functionality joining or splitting cells, adding, deleting and resizing rows, and that all.

Answer (score 0):

I've written the below to split multiple cells and to merge them together again, it's basic but it works well enough for me. I've used a comma to separate the cell values, and so it knows where to split the data back into separate cells if needed...

Javascript:

```
function mergeCells(cells, separator) {

    var data = [];

    $.each(cells, function(i, item) {
        data.push(item[0].innerHTML);
    });

    var result = $('<td/>', {
        'html': data.join(separator)
    });

    return result;
}

function splitCell(cell, separator) {

    var result = "";
    var data = (cell[0].innerHTML).split(separator);
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        result = result + "<td>{0}</td>".format(item);
    });

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
var merged = $('table').find('td:eq(1)');
var splitHtml = splitCell(merged, ", ");



var cell1 = $('table').find('td:eq(1)');
var cell2 = $('table').find('td:eq(2)');
var merged = mergeCells({
    1: cell1,
    2: cell2
}, ", ");
$(cell1).replaceWith(merged);
$(cell2).remove();
```